# Ajax response no longer returns true after updating to craft 4

Tags: form, ajax, craft4

I have a project that was initially built in Craft 3 and I'm upgrading it to Craft 4. I leverage ajax on one of the pages to save data to a user in the CMS. The following code worked in Craft 3 but no longer works in Craft 4. The ajax request submits correctly and the data is saved to the CMS but `data.success` no longer returns true. What's the ideal way to handle an ajax pass/fail in Craft 4?

```
$.ajax({
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    method: "POST",
    url: '',
    dataType: "json",
    data: formData
}).done(function(data) {
    if (data.success == true) {
        console.log(data, 'success')
    } else {
        console.log(data, 'fail')
    }
}).fail(function(data) {
    console.log(data, 'fail')
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controllers in Craft 4 generally use the [asSuccess](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/2eac9249964ccc553bf841c79b9ee44d58f16b61/src/web/Controller.php#L244-L272) and [asFailure](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/2eac9249964ccc553bf841c79b9ee44d58f16b61/src/web/Controller.php#L214-L242) methods, which return `200` and `400` status codes respectively, in response to JSON requests.

Both methods also send a `message` parameter in their response, in case there's something to report, so the following should work.

```javascript
$.ajax({...})
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log('success: ' + data.message);
    })
    .fail(function(data) {
        console.log('fail: ' + data.message);
    });
```

Comment: This worked, thank ya sir!